# VMware boxes cannot connect to the internet

Tags: ubuntu, centos7, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have many vm's and am having trouble connecting to the internet with any of them. I have tried include opening vmnetcfg.exe and resetting the network settings to defaults. When I log onto the vm's they say that they cannot detect a network card.

Unfortunately that didn't seem to have any affect. Would you have any ideas? Also this problem is effecting my ubuntu 18.04 box along with my centos box, but when I boot up my windows 7 vm it connects to the internet fine.

This is preventing me from working and is a huge issue. I have been trying to troubleshoot it for weeks now.

Comment: I would check the network adapter in your VMware client (e.g. VMware Player or Fusion) for that VM. It if it using NAT, that might explain it. Try changing from NAT to bridged, then reboot the VM and see if that resolved it.

Comment: After talking with some colleagues we solved the issue by performing a "sudo dhclient" I now have to do this every time I reboot but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo service network-manager start
```